# Customer session automatic destroy in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I'm using magento 2 with multistore in my base store customer login works fine but I have a problem with another store.

**When i try to login in customer account, and when I click on login then it works successfully and redirects to my account page, but after that when I refresh my account page or click on any links than it redirects to the login page.**

I already tried to disable all modules.

Please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Some details would be helpful here. You are facing this error in which magento version ? Are you facing it in fresh install or Have you added any module or done any sort of customization ?

Comment: @ReenaParekh Please check i edit my question

Answer (score -2):

@Nirav I have the same issue. Have you found a solution for it?

Newest Magento 2 @ Apache 2.4 @ PHP 7.0.5

Comment: no i didn't found anything yet..